# Do I need to pay for Flutter Packages

Tags: flutter

I am creating a flutter app for commercial use. I want to use flutter packages created by others. Do I have to pay for flutter packages created by someone?

Till now I am using packages created by flutter team or google Uploader.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS-style icons.

- cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_ml_vision:
  image_picker:
  url_launcher:
  firebase_storage:
  cloud_firestore:

I want to use rxdart, barcode_scan etc.,

Comment: Maybe, have you looked into each package license?

Comment: The packages that published in dart pub is completely free and open source, 
but In the meantime like other languages and tools, there will be commercial packages which you can buy.
https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter

Answer (score 0):

it is dependent on package license, Like:
https://github.com/flutter/cupertino_icons/blob/master/LICENSE

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
>   to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
>   copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>   furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on the kind of service you use.
For ex. If you use some kind of Text to Speech Provider the package might be available on [Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org). But the service provider might require you to pay to get a api key to use the service